# How can I use Trading Economics python package?

Tags: python

How to use the Trading Economics python package?

I have already installed the package. But using the `guest:guest` key I'm getting this error:

```py
$ login("guest:guest")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token '"guest:guest"'
```

Comment: What you show is bash, but "trading economics" is a python package which lives in the python shell. First type "python" (and hit enter) which then drops you into a python shell. Then follow the [trading economics tutorial](https://docs.tradingeconomics.com/#introduction) with the python code on the right. I.e. first type `import tradingeconomics as te` and then `te.login('Your_Key:Your_Secret')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run python commands in the bash. In order to make use of [Trading Economics API](https://docs.tradingeconomics.com/#introduction), create a new python file (or use python command-line) and use the following code in order to login:

If you already have an API key:

```
import tradingeconomics as te
te.login('Your_Key:Your_Secret')
```

If you don't have an API key and want to try a demo of the API:

```
import tradingeconomics as te
te.login()
```